# Hibernate 5 using variable name in SQLs generated although logical names provided in entity class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have recently upgraded spring and hibernate jars of  my project and  After upgrading i am always getting mapping exception  saying "Unable to find column with logical name"  in table ". I have explicitly mentioned logical name on entity classes but while SQLs are generated. physical names are of variable name.

```
New Versions 
hibernate --> 5.4.9
spring jars(core,aop,web,orm ....)--> 5.2.1
spring-data-jpa-->2.2.1
```

point balance entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pointbal")
public class PointBalance extends AbstractTrackableEntity<Long>  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2495698617037810698L;

@Audited
@Column(name = "employeeid", nullable = false, precision = 12)
private Long employeeId;

@Column(name = "enddtm", nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime endDateTime;


@Audited
@Column(name = "pointendbalamt", precision = 16, scale = 6)
private BigDecimal pointEndBalanceAmount;

@Column(name = "pointstartbalamt", precision = 16, scale = 6)
private BigDecimal pointStartBalanceAmount;

@Audited
@Column(name = "startdtm")
private LocalDateTime startDateTime;

@Version
@Column(name = "versioncnt", precision = 12)
private long versioncnt;

@ManyToOne (fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "transtatusid")
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
private TransactionStatus transactionStatus;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pointtypeid", nullable = false)
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
private PointBalanceType pointBalanceType;

@Override
@Id
@Column(name = "pointbalid")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "pointBalanceSequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "pointtype")
public class PointBalanceType extends AbstractReferenceDataEntity<Long> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3732362787488510501L;

@Column(nullable = false, precision = 1)
private BigDecimal decimalPlaceNum;

@Column(name = "ispointexpiredsw", nullable = false)
private boolean isPointExpiredSw;

@Column(name = "istimeexpiredsw", nullable = false)
private boolean isTimeExpiredSw;

@Column(name = "maxbalanceamt", nullable = false, precision = 16, scale = 6)
private BigDecimal maxBalanceAmount;

@Column(name = "minbalanceamt", nullable = false, precision = 16, scale = 6)
private BigDecimal minBalanceAmount;

@Column(name = "startbalanceamt", nullable = false, precision = 3)
private BigDecimal startBalanceAmount;

@Column(name = "ordernum", precision = 12)
private long orderNumber;

@Version
@Column(name = "versioncnt", precision = 12)
private long versioncnt;

@Override
@Id
@Column(name = "pointtypeid")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

SQLS Generated for finding all entities:

```
select pointbalan0_.pointbalid as pointbal1_0_, pointbalan0_.endDateTime as endDateT2_0_, pointbalan0_.pointBalanceType as pointBal3_0_, pointbalan0_.pointEndBalanceAmount as pointEnd4_0_, pointbalan0_.pointStartBalanceAmount as pointSta5_0_, pointbalan0_.startDateTime as startDat6_0_, pointbalan0_.transactionStatus as transact7_0_, pointbalan0_.versioncnt as versionc8_0_ from pointbal pointbalan0_
```

The physical names are different in Database and the sqls generated are different.

On further check found that Naming Strategy has been changed in hibernate 5. But as far as i know hibernate puts same logical name as physical names or has that been changed in hibernate 5?
How can i have same logical name and physical name?

Comment: You're mixing annotations on getters and annotations on fields. So half of them are ignored. You **must** be consistent (inside a class)

Comment: but this works fine when i am using hibernate 4